# Different page layout in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout, record-type

---

Is that possible to have different page layout for NEW, EDIT and VIEW? i.e;
I would like to have specific fields for each layout in salseforce1.
For creation of new records, I will have specific page layout.
for edition of new records, I will have another page layout.
For View of record, I will have another page Layout.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible out-of-the-box.   You have to design your page layout to optimize Edit/View, as well as on mobile.

One option to switch between "edit" ad "view" layouts is to inlude Read-Only fields (which won't appear on edit).

Otherwise, you have to build custom VisualForce, which should be able to distinguish user agents and change layouts on View/Edit modes.